# How does the defocus in a lightfield camera differ from a regular camera (i.e. a DSLR)?

Tags: light-field

I'm looking at using a camera to capture a focal stack -- same scene, no movement, just refocusing my DSLR at different focal lengths. I want to know if the defocus that's artificially done in post-processing on a lightfield camera's captured image is different from an image with a "real" defocus camera/lens? Do they also not have the magnification parallax problem when defocusing?

If I use an affine transformation to fix the magnification from my DSLR's focal stack, will it be the same as if I defocused the lightfield's images in post-processing?

Answer (score 1):

No, a light field camera will not have the parallax issue caused by changes in focal length/magnification when the focus distance is shifted... because light field cameras do not have focus mechanisms/lens elements that move.

But I don't know that the differences would be apparent in a properly aligned image stack.